# Very strange behaviour comparing undefined and false

Tags: javascript, comparison, logic, comparison-operators

I have this output in the console:

```
console.log((!undefined)==(!false)) // true (fine)
console.log((!!undefined)==(!!false)) // true (still fine)
```

As I know, `!!x==x`, isn't it?

```
console.log((undefined)==(false)) // false
```

Can anyone tell me why this returns false?

Is not true that `!!false==false` and `!!undefined==undefined`?

Comment: The falsy `undefined` value is coerced into `false` when used in a logic operator like `!`: http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript

Comment: Any reference (official) to this?

Comment: [logical not operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9) although `!undefined` is `true` of course.

Comment: See the ECMAScript standard's [logical NOT operator](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.9) which calls [toBoolean](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.2).  `toBoolean` is where the truthy/falsy magic happens, listed as explicit cases in the standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  `!!x` does *not* return x.  `!undefined` *coerces* `undefined` *to a boolean*, `false`, then finds `!((bool)undefined)`=`!false`, if we use C++ cast notation.  So `!!undefined` gives `!!((bool)undefined)`=`!!(false)`=`!true`=`false`, rather than `undefined`.

Comment: Any (official) reference highlighting this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Undefined is not a `boolean` type, like `false` so when you compare them directly, they are not equal.

See [here](http://www.mapbender.org/JavaScript_pitfalls%3a_null,_false,_undefined,_NaN) for other comparison pitfalls.

```
typeof(undefined)
"undefined"

typeof(false)
"boolean"
```

Comment: `==` vs `===` makes no difference when comparing `false` to `undefined/null` It especially makes no difference in this situation when everything is converted to same type before even compared.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I had meant. I updated my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(!undefined)
// true
console.log(!false)
// true
console.log(!!undefined)
// false
console.log(!!false)
// false
```